# Custom routing of mail from mail server(Postfix, Dovecot) to tigase xmpp server

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot, tigase

we need to reroute mail as xmpp packet from postfix to tigase server. Does anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to write a  milter for postfix similar to http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#fax